# Default value for vuex action payload?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to come up with a nicer way to have a default value for a vuex action payload property, right now I'm using an if-else to check if the passed payload object has a delay property, if it doesn't I set the value to default and you can imagine the rest.

Is there a nicer way to do this in fewer lines? I'm sure there must be.

Here is my action:

```
showModal ( {commit}, modalPayload ) {

        let delay;

        if(modalPayload.delay == undefined){
            delay = 3000;
        }
        else{
            delay = modalPayload.delay
        }

        commit('SHOW_MODAL',  modalPayload);
        setTimeout(function(){
            commit('HIDE_MODAL');
        }, delay);

    },
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a default value using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
showModal ({ commit }, modalPayload) {
  const { delay = 3000 } = modalPayload

  commit('SHOW_MODAL', modalPayload);
  setTimeout(() => commit('HIDE_MODAL'), delay);

}
```

Also, if you don't need passing `delay` to the `commit`, you can destructure the second function parameter:

```
showModal ({ commit }, { delay = 3000, ...modalPayload }) {
  commit('SHOW_MODAL', modalPayload);
  setTimeout(() => commit('HIDE_MODAL'), delay);
}
```